# How to "UNNEST" JSON objects in sql or bigquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, google-bigquery

in my SQL server i have an attribute or column with this value

```
{"cases": "1", "deaths": "0", "icuBeds": {"capacity": "", "currentUsageCovid": "", `"currentUsageTotal": ""}, "newCases": "0", "newDeaths": "0", "hospitalBeds": {"capacity": "", "currentUsageCovid": "", "currentUsageTotal": ""}, "negativeTests": "", "positiveTests": "", "contactTracers": "", "vaccinesDistributed": "", "vaccinesAdministered": "", "vaccinationsCompleted": "", "vaccinationsInitiated": ""}
```

I am trying run some SQL queries on this data in BigQuery however I just found out I cannot run any queries on these objects since the properties are stored as strings.

This data is being inserted into my SQL server from my NODEJS server which is running api calls and storing the JSON formatted data into the SQL Server.

What are some solutions I can do so that I can do some sql analysis in BigQuery? How can I store the data or how can I unnest the data so that I can access these properties?

Comment: Also, how (if at all) is node related to this task?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can use JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar) on the string text with the JSON path you want to extract.

Example:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fieldName, '$.cases') as cases
FROM tableName
```

Comment: what does $.cases mean here?

Comment: its the JSON path for the first variable in your JSON example above ({"cases": "1"}), should return 1.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work @justrying?